# Issue including multi security-content-policy on firebase-hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, next.js, firebase-hosting

Next.js / Firebase app hosted on Firebase-hosting.

I have added one security script in the header of the hosting configuration: (and this is working fine)

```
 // Old value: 
"value": "frame-ancestors 'self'"
```

Now I added two more scripts:

```
// New value:             
"value": "frame-ancestors 'self'; default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'"
```

After deploying the UI and the app is broken, I did research and saw that people adding those scripts in the same way as me.

Does anyone faced a similar problem, or maybe seen a problem in my approach?

firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
   ...
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "x-frame-options",
            "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
          },
          {
            "key": "content-security-policy",

           //After deployment UI is broken
            "value": "frame-ancestors 'self'; default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: The `default-src 'none'` content policy means that by default, no content should be loaded from any source. Where `frame-ancestors 'self'` means allow your app to be embedded within an iframe on the same origin (same domain) as your app. It restricts framing from any other origins. And `script-src 'self'` means scripts can only be loaded from the same origin (self). This restricts loading scripts from any external sources. As all the content-policies are counteracting with each other hence the app is getting broken. If this is not then please share the `firebase-debug.log` logs

Comment: Does that comment help to solve your query if so acknowledge it, so I will post as an answer so other community members will also get answer for this question.

Comment: @RohitKharche yes it helped, default-src 'none' was a problem, cus it blocks load even from some firebase resources and others like google analytics and stripe... so I removed default-src 'none' in order to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are giving counteracting `content-security-policy` policies as in your case :

- `frame-ancestors 'self'` :  Means allow your app to be embedded within an iframe on the same origin (same domain) as your app. It restricts framing from any other origins.
- `default-src 'none'` : means by default, no content should be loaded from any source. This is a very restrictive setting, and you'll need to add additional directives to allow specific sources from where your app can load content.
- `script-src 'self'` : means scripts can only be loaded from the same origin (self). This restricts loading scripts from any external sources.
  Combining these directives you have significantly tightened the security of your app by disallowing loading content from any external sources and restricting script loading to the same origin.

As removing `default-src 'none'` helped, because by removing that policy the restriction for getting content from any other source than `self` has been lifted.

You can go through [this guide](https://web.dev/csp/) which explains all security headers. You can also test your policies [here](https://report-uri.com/)

Reference : [**Configure headers**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers) and [**Content Security Policy (CSP)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)